# how could i write this jquery code in proper oop way

Tags: javascript, jquery

A month back i start writing my first serious front-end heavy website, the idea was to create a custom cms driven 1 page website which internally hold over 100 pages.

so the url will always be same but everytime user click any link based on navigation hierarchy it will animate, load data using ajax call and append a hash in url which can be used for sharing  link, i ended up using something like this :

links:

```
<a data-alias="#treasurysales" rel="get_content.php?id=62" data-content="vert_21_63" data-target="vert_21_63_tar" href="">(Treasury Sales )
```

container :

```
<li id="vert_2_19_tar" class="hs-home-li" style="display: none;">
```

here is how my js looks like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        //hash handling
        $("a[data-alias],li[data-alias]").live("click",hashHandler);
        $("a[rel *= php]:not('.apply,a[data-direction],.bod')").live("click",ajaxHandler);
        $(".static-link").live("click",static_link)

        //main navigation
        $(".horizontal-scroll > li").not(":first-child").hide();
        $(".left-nav ul li a").live("click",vertNav);
        $(".tab-nav ul li a[data-target]").live("click",horzNav);   
        $(".small",".hs-home-li").hide();
        $(".small:first",".hs-home-li").show();
        $(".tab-sub-nav a").live("click",tabNav);
               // around 100 lines


})
```

here is how my function.js looks like

```
var vTarget, 
lastvTarget = $("site-vertical-scroll>li:first"), 
hTarget,
lasthTarget,
tabTarget, //around 15-20 var 
var hashHandler = function(){};
var hash_location = function(){};
var hash_location = function(){}; //around 100 function
```

after reaching 1000+line js i realized this is not the way to do it properly. my code is very dependent on dom , tightly coupled, unmaintainable.

i read several books on oop js, pattern, testing and best practice but i am really lacking in architecting my js everything else comes after.

i will appreciate a lot if someone can tell me how to write above code in proper oop way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may wish to [write it as a plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring). For an application, I have a number of "plugins" which represent the full behavior of a particular page. I tend to follow this structure for pages with lots of functionality, that other content may need to interact with.

```
(function($) {
    var $m = $.mycompany||{};

    $m.myPage = new function(element, options) {
        this.$element = $(element);
        this.options = options;

        // i initialize everything here
    };

    $m.myPage.prototype = {
       someMethod: function() {
          // these are what i consider "API"  methods for my plugin. other components may need to interact with functionality of this plugin, and this is how I expose it.
       }
       // etc.
    }

    $m.myPage.defaults = {} // defaults on this object

    $.fn.myPage = function(options) {
        options = $.extend({}, $m.myPage.defaults, options);

        this.each(function() {
          var $this = $(this);
          if ($this.data('myPage')) return; // plugin already initialized
          $this.data('myPage', new $m.myPage(this, options));
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Then, in a page, I could do:

```
$(document).myPage({myOption:'whatever'});
```

Other functionality can access that plugin via

```
$(document).data('myPage').someMethod();
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider a framework like [Backbone.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/) which will help you structure you code and provide you with several important things:

- Management of Routing
- Event management generally at the "view" layer
- Data management through models
- and binding of Models to the UI through templates